# MVC3 preserve a complex object in memory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, serialization, transactions

We've an ASP.Net MVC3 based web app for Claim entry & management. To simplify, consider Claim as an Order. A Claim can have child objects and one of its child object can have sub-child. Like ...

(i.e. Claim --> Items --> Files)

We need a transaction like mechanism. That is during Claim entry user can add / edit / delete child or sub-child objects. And at the end he can "**Accept**" (commit) all changes (to database) OR "**Cancel**" (rollback/reject) all.

What are the options I've got to technically implement this "transactional" feature which supports Accept / Cancel mechanism explained. Here're some of my thoughts -

1. **Fetch the whole Claim object and presist it in session via serialization**. All the changes will be made to this Claim object "in memory" and at the end user can decide to accept/cancel.
2. **Add a "xxxx_transit" table for each entity(xxxx)**. All operations will be done on this temp transit table and when committed we finally apply the changes to the actual xxxx table.
3. **Knockout approach** - store the Claim model on client side, apply changes to it. UI binding will reflect the changes instantly. And finally when committed - apply the changes to the db.

My assessment

> 1. We've done it and we used ASP.Net session state service but the
>      object serialization affects the performance!
> 2. Would the extra complexity be worth? Especially when compared to the performance gain over #1.
> 3. I believe this will increase complexity and operation
>      handling on GUI layer. Is it safe?

Which one would you suggest? If misleading, forget my thoughts and please share what you think would be best?

Thank you.

Comment: You always have to trust the client at some level. Taking it all in at once vs. piece by piece has the same "safeness" to it. Both need to be validated correctly. I am working on my first client-side driven Durandal/KO project and I think that it works amazingly well. Don't forget that in this latter approach, the page, as it is, affects the object lifetime - refresh -> no more data. Design the user experience with this in mind, such as separating steps or using checkpoints.

Comment: I get it. But in my case I've some file uploads associated with the object. Hopefully KO would persist the object hierarchy on client side until postback (Accept) but I've to upload files as the user selects them. Things are maintained at two places! Besides I've done some KO and it did seem a great user experience but viewmodel implementation has to be maintained or it can get complex!

Comment: I've not done files, but that doesn't seem that hard. Use an async upload technique (HTML5 or iframes) and associate the file by means of a GUID or similar nonce or ID. Only store the Name/GUID client-side. The server will either accept the "finish" request in the near future or some automated job can reap the temporary files if they are not used within a threshold.